kotlin-gradle-plugin UnknownPluginException from a local maven repo
I have to create a local maven repo, so the android project will be able to build just from this local repo alone.
From the logs it seems like plugin was actually resolved.
But for some reason I keep getting the following error.
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.9.22'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Can someone help me with that?
Short log:
Attempting to resolve component for org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin:1.9.22 using repositories [maven]
Loading file:/C:/Users/test/Documents/Github/Work/test/local-maven-repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/android/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin/1.9.22/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin-1.9.22.pom
Attempting to resolve component for org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugins-bom:1.9.22 using repositories [maven]
Loading file:/C:/Users/test/Documents/Github/Work/test/local-maven-repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugins-bom/1.9.22/kotlin-gradle-plugins-bom-1.9.22.pom
Metadata file found for module 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugins-bom:1.9.22' in repository 'maven'.
Loading file:/C:/Users/test/Documents/Github/Work/test/local-maven-repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugins-bom/1.9.22/kotlin-gradle-plugins-bom-1.9.22.module
Recording module descriptor in cache: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugins-bom:1.9.22 [changing = false]
Using org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugins-bom:1.9.22 from Maven repository 'maven'
Loading file:/C:/Users/test/Documents/Github/Work/test/local-maven-repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugins-bom/1.9.22/kotlin-gradle-plugins-bom-1.9.22.pom
Downloaded artifact 'kotlin-gradle-plugins-bom-1.9.22.pom (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugins-bom:1.9.22)' from resolver: maven
Flushing resolved configuration data in Binary store in C:\Users\test\.gradle\.tmp\gradle17832654540797845168.bin. Wrote root 2.
Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of detachedConfiguration1' completed
        
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.9.22'] was not found in any of the following sources:
    
    Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
    Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin:1.9.22')
    Searched in the following repositories: maven // this is my local repo.

Here goes the full log: https://gist.github.com/romanlapa/d164589bb5f19e0416500b2f623eda7f
What I have done.

I have used maven to resolve most of the dependencies, mvn dependency:resolve.
I have manually changed some folder names and paths to the files, because for some reason gradle was expecting them in a different format.

For example org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin-1.9.22 has a different name by default: kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.9.22 .
My configuration.
settings.build.gradle:
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    maven(uri("$rootDir/local-maven-repo"))

  }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
  repositories {
    maven(uri("$rootDir/local-maven-repo"))
  }
}

rootProject.name = "MyApplication4"

include(":app")

build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.0.0"
    kotlin("android") version "1.9.22"
    //id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.22"
    id("maven-publish")
}
...


Are you manually copying dependencies onto a file system in a maven repo format?

Most of it was done my mvn dependency:resolve. The rest I was copying manually according to build errors. It print's out the expexcted path and file name with --debug option.

Gradle plugins are published in their own special Maven artifact so that Gradle can resolve them from a repo using their id alone.
This artifact has coordinates:

groupId: the id of the plugin (eg org.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
artifactId: the id of the plugin appended by .gradle.plugin (eg org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin)
version: the version of the plugin

The artifact then has a POM file with a dependency which is the artifact with the JAR containing the compiled plugin code. (You can use the POM from the actual plugin of course.)
You can either manually arrange your local repo with the plugin POM in this fashion or use this information to write a little Gradle project to republish the plugin using the Maven Publish plugin. (I would recommend the latter. Full details of how to do that is probably outside the scope of this question.)
You look to have declared the repository properly so, arranged in this way Gradle should then be able to resolve the plugin from your repo.

You are correct. I have laso figured it out using --debug option. I have manually created a new folder with artifacts like you have said. But as you can see in the log at line https://gist.github.com/romanlapa/d164589bb5f19e0416500b2f623eda7f#file-log-txt-L2945 sadly it does not help. It fails even when logs are indicating it found everything.
Path: gradle/localMvnRepository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/android/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin/1.9.22/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin-1.9.22.pom

In addition to that, removing this new folder, allowed me to finish a sync once, but after a reopening the project it started failing again.

And even more to it. I have just realised that it works every time if I add this.
resolutionStrategy {
eachPlugin {
if (requested.id.id == "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" ||
requested.id.id == "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") {
// Map the plugin ID to the specific Maven coordinates
useModule("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.22")
}
}
}
It is a solution, but I would prefer to avoid workarounds.

Are you certain you have the correct POM file etc in the maven repo for the plugin? I don't know if all the hashes of the POM etc are necessary as well, which you see produced automatically. I suggest trying to resolve the plugin as a regular dependency (ie use the coordinates described above), which will show whether your issue is related to it being a plugin or generally it not being resolvable as a dependency in its current configuration.

I have created a gist with paths and contents.
https://gist.github.com/Turbozanik/7add380b2b4e11df5b07007410d61512
The only thing I am not sure about, is that was I supposed to change the pom file groupId too, in order for all this to work?
So far it really feels like since plugin has a custom path, it can't find related bom/misc artifacts.

There is a lot more in your POM than in the real one. I'd be copying the real one. Not sure why you are bringing the BOM into it etc. And yes, I'd make sure the POM groupId etc match or you will surely have problems

You are right. I am not sure why, but it is different. It might be that maven resolved it badly, or I changed it during my debuggin. But after that change it worked. Final answer would be to do full dependency resolve by maven and manually change plugins to what gradle expects.

Nice one pleased you got it to work.

That realy realy worked. Many thanks!
